# Constraints on Type Parameters and error "cannot implicitly convert type"

Tags: c#, inheritance, constraints

I am working on one project and I have a question regarding the converting type.

The problem:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConsoleApplication2.Imp.StorageImp' to
>   'ConsoleApplication2.Storage(ConsoleApplication2.Item)

My simple code:

```
public interface IItem
{
    void Add();
}

public abstract class Item : IItem
{
    public abstract void Add();
}

public class ItemImp : Item
{
    public override void Add()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IStorage<T> where T : Item
{
    List<T> Get(); 
    bool Add(T item);
}

public abstract class Storage<T> : IStorage<T> where T : Item
{
    public abstract bool Add(T item);
    public abstract List<T> Get();
}

public class StorageImp : Storage<ItemImp>
{
    public override bool Add(ItemImp item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override List<ItemImp> Get()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Problem code with convert(I trying convert implemantation to base class):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Storage<Item> storage = new StorageImp();
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: You cannot convert a derived class to its base class, you can cast it though

Comment: Why cannot I convert the derived class to the base class?

Comment: Why do you have so many layers of abstraction here? Since the abstract base classes don't really provide any base functionality, you are just muddying up the type system. If your actual implementation follows your example, I'd ditch the abstract classes and let the concrete ones implement the interface directly.

Comment: In real project abstraction class Storage have additional code. But maybe your right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler is reporting error because `Storage<Item>` is not base class of `StorageImp`. instead `Storage<ItemImp>` is base class of `StorageImp`.

So replace

```
Storage<Item> storage = new StorageImp();
```

with

```
Storage<ItemImp> storage = new StorageImp();
```

**Update**

If you want abstraction from the implementation of the class "ItemImp" as commented then you need to make `StorageImp` generic just as below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Storage<Item> storage = new StorageImp<Item>();
    }
}



public interface IItem
{
    void Add();
}

public abstract class Item : IItem
{
    public abstract void Add();
}

public class ItemImp : Item
{
    public override void Add()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IStorage<T> where T : Item
{
    List<T> Get();
    bool Add(T item);
}

public abstract class Storage<T> : IStorage<T> where T : Item
{
    public abstract bool Add(T item);
    public abstract List<T> Get();
}

public class StorageImp<T> : Storage<T> where T: Item
{
    public override bool Add(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override List<T> Get()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, but I need an abstraction from the implementation of the class "ItemImp". It may be something else?

Comment: @AntonGorinenko Then you need to make `StorageImp` type also generic having contraint that generic type needs to be `Item`

Comment: The class StorageImp should work with specific implementations of base class Item. For example, ItemImp...

Comment: I made StorageImp type also generic, having contraint that generic type needs to be Item. Thank Jenish Rabadiya for idea